# Windows Curl Returning (35) Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: windows, curl, windows-10

Recently python started throwing errors when it tried to connect to the internet. Autodesk Fusion360 had this issue aswell. I believe I have tracked the issue down to curl.exe returning error 35.

Command: `curl https://google.com`

Response:

```
curl: (35) Send failure: Connection was reset
```

For some reason curl works perfectly in safe mode.

Also if you need any more information just comment and I'll get back to you as soon as I can.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried booting up my PC with nonessenial services disabled as described [here](https://help.ea.com/en/help/faq/how-to-clean-boot-your-pc/) but to no avail.

I have also tried using a vpn but that doesn't seem to work either. The only thing that is currently working is doing it in safe mode.